# HTML Image Maps stopped working?

Tags: html, imagemap

For several years I have used this method to cut to the chase with one of my clients, and for years this has worked. But for some reason this one particular set of image maps fails to be working and I can't see the spot thats messing me up.

http://newyorkbarshow.com/index.php?loc=seminars

```
<img src="/imgs/i2012/seminar2012-1.png" alt="page 1" width="580" height="916" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="219,225,274,282" href="/index.php?loc=article&id=128" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="518,216,573,270" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=131" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="219,303,274,357" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=129" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="520,279,575,331" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=132" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="220,386,274,440" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="318,396,350,427" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="354,397,385,427" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="392,397,421,427" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="428,396,457,427" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="464,395,495,430" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="517,385,573,440" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=114" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="223,509,274,564" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="155,575,212,630" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="218,576,275,632" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=128" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="518,549,573,604" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=133" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="517,633,571,690" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=28" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="220,676,274,730" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="219,776,273,830" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=130" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="519,820,572,872" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=139" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="301,821,513,900" href="/index.php?loc=article&id=141" />
</map>
<br />
<img src="/imgs/i2012/seminar2012-2.png" alt="page 2" border="0" usemap="#Map2" />
<map name="Map2" id="Map2">
  <area shape="rect" coords="213,220,271,277" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=134" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="515,222,570,278" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=143" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="215,288,268,344" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="215,372,271,427" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=135" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="215,458,271,510" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=136" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="515,430,570,486" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="218,522,273,585" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=138" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="514,523,570,576" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=134" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="515,588,570,643" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="217,612,270,667" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=140" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="215,693,271,749" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=142" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="515,744,570,800" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=145" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="295,223,510,342" href="/index.php?loc=article&id=144" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="11,456,213,569" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=137" />
</map>
<br />
<img src="/imgs/i2012/seminar2012-3.png" alt="page 3" border="0" usemap="#Map3" />
<map name="Map3" id="Map3">
  <area shape="rect" coords="345,480,550,493" herf="http://nyworldwineandspiritscompetition.com" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="393,543,578,779" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=127" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="17,546,208,779" herf="/index.php?loc=article&id=x" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="260,731,348,742" herf="http://doctickets.com" />
</map>
```

At first I thought maybe since Im on a mac its something to do with the browser support, but after trying it on all browsers on both mac and 2 pcs i realize its not. Funny thing is
http://newyorkbarshow.com/index.php?loc=archive-2011 is last years and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure wether this is the solution but you typed **herf** instead of **href** in most links.

Comment: That was the fix, I can't believe I did that, good catch thank you